# ng-grid row border becomes invisible after using cellClass

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, row, ng-grid

When I use cellClass and color entire column, the row border becomes invisible. Here is the plunker.  http://plnkr.co/edit/4IeQQBTIe8sgHVEBUTAp?p=preview .Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add something like:

```
.ngCellText{
   border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
}
```

to your last loaded stylesheet.

**style.css** in this forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lCUCGUWdOsBH11VB0eQu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

again, I'll have to start with saying, that I'm no CSS pro here, but I think the 'issue' is caused by the included angular-ui stylesheet.

They probably have their reasons for it but here is what's causing the missing border:
class .ngCellText adds a padding of 5px pushing the bottom border out of sight.

Attached a screenshot for better understanding:
[image]

I would suggest to look into the angular-ui documentation and see how they recommend using it for similar usecases, but as a quickfix try decreasing the padding:

[image]

There is probably also a lesson about border-collapse to be learned here.... but as said I'm no css pro and I'm too lazy to look it up :P

Hope this helps, a bit